# Using a Promise inside of a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I am new to using `Promise` and cannot quite get this right.

I am trying to create a situation where I load the google maps API script if an element on the page requires it. This part I have got working, what I am struggling with is if there are more than 1 elements on the page that requires google maps API I need to only load the script once.

Here is what I have so far.

index.html

```
<div class="map" id="map-1" data-module="map" style="height: 100vh;"></div>

<div class="map" id="map-2" data-module="map" style="height: 100vh;"></div>

<div class="map" id="map-3" data-module="map" style="height: 100vh;"></div>

<div class="map" id="map-4" data-module="map" style="height: 100vh;"></div>
```

loadGoogleMapsApi.js

```
export default class LoadGoogleMapsAPI {
    constructor() {

        this.apiKey = '********';

        // set a globally scoped callback if it doesn't already exist
        /* eslint no-underscore-dangle: 0 */
        if (!window._GoogleMapsApi) {
            this.callbackName = '_GoogleMapsApi.mapLoaded';
            window._GoogleMapsApi = this;
            window._GoogleMapsApi.mapLoaded = this.mapLoaded.bind(this);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Load the Google Maps API javascript
     */
    async load() {
        if (!this.promise) {
            this.promise = await new Promise((resolve) => {
                this.resolve = resolve;

                if (typeof window.google === 'undefined') {
                    const script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.src = `//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${window._GoogleMapsApi.apiKey}&callback=${window._GoogleMapsApi.callbackName}`;
                    script.async = true;
                    document.body.append(script);
                } else {
                    this.resolve();
                }
            });
        }

        return this.promise;
    }

    /**
     * Globally scoped callback for the map loaded
     */
    mapLoaded() {
        if (this.resolve) {
            this.resolve();
        }
    }
}
```

map.js

```
import GoogleMapsApi from '../utils/loadGoogleMapsApi';

export default class MapViewModel {
    constructor(module) {

        this.module = module;

        const gmapApi = new GoogleMapsApi();

        gmapApi.load().then(() => {
            // safe to start using the API now
            new google.maps.Map(this.module, {
                center: { lat: 51.5074, lng: -0.1278 },
                zoom: 11,
            });
            // etc.
        });
    }

    static init() {
        const instances = document.querySelectorAll('[data-module="map"]');

        instances.forEach((module) => {
            const options = JSON.parse(module.getAttribute('data-map-settings'));
            new MapViewModel(module, options);
        });
    }
}

MapViewModel.init();
```

The issue is in the `load()` function (i think). I have tried all sorts of different things and this is the closest I get. It seems that the code either does not wait and puts the script tag in 4 times OR the code resolves before the script tag has loaded and my `google.maps.Map(...)` doesn't work.

Any help I can get will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Luke.

---

**UPDATE**

**SOLVED**

New code thanks to @jcubic helping me finally reach a solution.

loadGoogleMapsApi.js

```
export default class LoadGoogleMapsAPI {
    /**
     * Load the Google Maps API javascript
     */
    static load() {
        this.apiKey = '******';

        if (!this.promise) {
            this.promise = new Promise((resolve) => {

                if (typeof window.google === 'undefined') {
                    const script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.onload = resolve;
                    script.src = `//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${this.apiKey}`;
                    script.async = true;
                    document.body.append(script);
                }
            });
        }

        return this.promise;
    }
}
```

map.js

```
import GoogleMapsApi from '../utils/loadGoogleMapsApi';

export default class MapViewModel {
    constructor(module) {

        this.module = module;

        GoogleMapsApi.load().then(() => {
            // safe to start using the API now
            new google.maps.Map(this.module, {
                center: { lat: 51.5074, lng: -0.1278 },
                zoom: 11,
            });
            // etc.
        });
    }

    static init() {
        const instances = document.querySelectorAll('[data-module="map"]');

        instances.forEach((module) => {
            const options = JSON.parse(module.getAttribute('data-map-settings'));
            new MapViewModel(module, options);
        });
    }
}

MapViewModel.init();
```

So the 2 parts to the solution are making loadGoogleMapsApi.js a static class and moving the `constructor` code inside the `load()` function. Then also changing the `load()` function to not use async/await and adding `script.onload = resolve`.

Comment: You can delete `mapLoaded` function/method it's not needed anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this `this.promise = await new Promise((resolve) => {` this.promise will not be a promise but value that promise resolve to, this is how async/await works. You're resolving it with undefined (no value to resolve()) so `this.promise` is undefined (it's always false).

**EDIT** you also need to call this.resolve otherwise if you call in a loop you execute it multiple times before it finish, you probably also want to resolve the promise when script will be ready:

```
load() {
    if (!this.promise) {
        this.promise = new Promise((resolve) => {

            if (typeof window.google === 'undefined') {
                const script = document.createElement('script');
                script.onload = resolve;
                script.src = `//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${window._GoogleMapsApi.apiKey}&callback=${window._GoogleMapsApi.callbackName}`;
                script.async = true;
                document.body.append(script);

            }
        });
    }

    return this.promise;
}
```

Comment: ok, this sort of makes sense, so should I remove `this.promise = `?

Comment: @lukehillonline just remove async/await, you already have promise just return it.

Comment: When i remove the async/await I then get the script appended to the body 4 times.

Comment: @lukehillonline no, because you have `if (!this.promise)`

Comment: @lukehillonline async/await just wrap your code into a promise, and you don't need this because you're creating promise in that function.

Comment: please see my update. With my load function like that, i get the script on the page 4 times. tested and confirmed

Comment: The problem is that you never call `this.resolve()` just put it inside `if`, I've update the answer.

Comment: If the promise never resolve it's probably because the browser don't support onload on scripts if that's the case you will need to create setInterval or setTimeout to check if window.google is defined.

Comment: Unfortunately it is more complicated than that. Your answer assumes the script is loaded on the page and executed instantly. I used Google Maps API `callback` query string to pass the `mapLoaded()` function which then resolves the promise. This should ensure the Google Maps API has successfully loaded before the `.then()` is executed. So I need the `Promise` to wait until that callback is triggered.

Comment: @lukehillonline yes I've just notice that after I've commented and updated the answer.

Comment: I have copied your code into my solution and unfortunately, I am still getting the script loaded on the page 4 times.

Comment: @lukehillonline also another error you have, `const gmapApi = new GoogleMapsApi();` need to be static otherwise each instance will have different this.promise and it will not matter what you put inside that class.

Comment: please excuse my poor understanding but to achieve this I need to set my constructor inside `LoadGoogleMapsAPI` as static like so: `static constructor() { ...`? P.s. thanks for all your help so far.